# Why this task hangs?

Tags: c#, task

```
[TestMethod]
public void Y()
{
    int i = 0;
    new Task(() => i++).Wait();

    Assert.AreEqual(1, i);
}
```

For what reason is the Task in the above example waiting forever? How should I `Wait()` for the Task so it does not hang?

Comment: Does your testing framework support asynchronous tests? If so, you should probably re-work this to be async throughout and remove the explicit `Wait`.

Comment: The Task is never started.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did not **start** the `Task`. Try this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Y()
{
    int i = 0;
    Task task = new Task(() => i++);
    task.Start();
    task.Wait();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, i);
}
```

or even better (as Damien suggested) use [`Task.Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run):

```
[TestMethod]
public void Y()
{
    int i = 0;
    Task.Run(() => i++).Wait();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, i);
}
```

Comment: Or better, get in the habit of using `Task.Run` to create hot tasks.

Answer (score 4):

There are generally 3 reasons why `someTask.Wait` "hangs":

1. You've deadlocked the synchronization context that was captured
2. There is no synchronization context at all
3. You're waiting for a task that is never started

In the first example, windows forms applications would be a likely scenario but the `[TestMethod]` attribute tells a different story. You can get out of this mess however by using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` but before going down this route please read up on the subject. `async/await` looks easy on the surface but you're treading into a minefield.

In unit test projects you need a test runner that processes messages posted to the synchronization context. This *could* be a likely problem if you're using a test runner that does not.

However, in your current method you're not starting the task. A task never started never completes.

However, if you start the task you *might* end up with point 2 above.

**Conclusion**: Make sure you start your task, and if that still blocks take a look at the unit test framework you're using.

To start the task:

```
var task = new Task(() => i++);
task.Start();
task.Wait();
```

Also, in general unless you build some kind of framework around handling tasks you should probably not use `new Task(...)` at all but instead opt for `Task.Run`:

```
Task.Run(() => i++).Wait();
```

If your test runner supports async/await properly I would rather rewrite the entire method to be async:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Y()
{
    int i = 0;
    await new Task(() => i++);

    Assert.AreEqual(1, i);
}
```